# Rotating an object via JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

I have a basic understanding on jQuery's animate() method and properties, but I want to take it even further...What resources do developers study to help rotate images via JavaScript / jQuery?

My current thought process is assuming that there are mathematical functions that you can store into variables and plug into the animate() jQuery sequence in order to see an object rotate 180 degrees on click.  then when you click the object again, it rotates another 180 degrees.

My end goal is to have a < div > which uses a css background image, to all be rotated.  The image itself will be a png file with transparency to help make the rotation appear more seamless.  If that sounds stupid, please let me know - but that is what I'm picturing in my head...

I'm just looking for direction on learning this process

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform

Comment: Depending on exactly what you are looking for, CSS may be easier. Is there a specific reason it needs to be Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: I was thinking of CSS3 to do that while driving to work, but then it hit me that not too many browsers support that - Chrome will for sure, but everyone else may not...  I want it to be JavaScript based this way it works in more browsers. - That's my reason

Comment: JavaScript cannot do that directly, it can only be using to manipulate the related CSS properties, or a canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either manipulate the CSS [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transforms?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FUsing_CSS_transforms) properties, or add the image to a canvas element, where you can use a native rotate method, or manually reposition the image's pixels.

Comment: My only question to that is which direction is supported in more browsers...

Comment: See http://caniuse.com/#search=transforms, http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Basic_animations